# Is my code under deep recursion risk? Boost::asio

Tags: c++, recursion, boost, asio

I just learnt about deep recursion and I'm not sure if my code, which uses boost::asio is under the risk of deep recursion, therefor, a stack overflow. Here is the code:

```
    //read_buf is member of Client, defined as : asio::streambuf read_buf;

 void Client::handleRead(asio::error_code& ec)
{

        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << &read_buf;


        std::string readRemainder = ss.str();
        
        size_t index;

        while ((index = readRemainder.find('\x1F')) != std::string::npos)
        {
                            //process the message here
            readRemainder.erase(readRemainder.begin(), readRemainder.begin() + index + 1);

        }
        asio::async_read_until(*sock, read_buf, '\x1F', bind(&Client::handleRead, this, ec));
    }


}
```

Since this code uses async_read_until, It exists the method right after calling itself recursively. But since it exists, I thought there wouldn't be a stack overflow issue. But when I shared the code with an AI, it said there is a potential deep recursion risk and a potential stack overflow issue.

Do you think there is a deep recursion / stack overflow risk with this code?

Comment: There are two parts to sound recursive code: an end case, which stops the recursion, and a recursive call which moves closer to the end case. So, for example, `if (i == 0) return; else do_recursive(i - 1);`. This doesn't seem to have either. Why is the code recursing in the first place? What moves the recursive case closer to the end case? What is the end case?

Comment: End case is when the client gets removed, so as long as its alive, it tries to read data from the socket. But I'm just confused, since asio:asynch_read_until is a non-blocking operation, would this still be considered recursive?

Comment: This isn't recursive. But it will loop infinitely.

Comment: One thing that surprises many people is that AIs don't know anything about anything. What you get if you ask a a question is an answer that looks similar to answers to questions that look similar to your question.

Comment: @interjay yes, that's what I was thinking about. This shouldn't be considered recursive since async_read_until is nonblocking. So there shouldn't be any problem , right?

Comment: @molbdnilo yup, I know. More than half the time it gives wrong answers. But among the potential risks, this one bothered me a little so I wanted to ask others if  there is a potential risk I'm unaware about.

Comment: @molbdnilo I asked an AI to explain your comment, but I didn't understand the answer :D

Comment: Blocking or non-blocking doesn't matter; what does `asio::async_read_until` do with the function object that is passed to it? If it calls the function object you've got a recursive call, and you'll continue to get more nested recursive calls until the client gets removed?

Comment: @PeteBecker well, as far as I know, it keeps reading until it reads '\x1F' , puts everything inside the read_buf then calls handle_read .  that's what makes this potentially recursive, but since its not blocking, only 1 instance of the function should be inside the stack, logically. Am I missing something?

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger and watch what happens with the call to `asio::async_read_until`. If that doesn't answer all of your questions, you'll be able to come back here and make this question a better one.